# Include or set UTF-8 in Pascal

Tags: utf-8, pascal

I don't know how can I set UTF-8 in Pascal. 
So I need write this letters: Š,Č,Ž and I don't wanna use this version: `&#268;`

Comment: Which Pascal? FreePascal? Delphi? old Delphi? They all handle that differently

Comment: Also please specify what do you want to do with these utf-8 strings?

Comment: FreePascal. I want writing with this strings.

Comment: If you are using Write/WriteLn to Windows console, you have to change default console font which doesn't support UTF-8 characters. Try using Consolas font.

Comment: @SrđanTot It's same if I change font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple string constant works, if you save the .pas file  utf-8 encoded.

```
'Š,Č,Ž and I'
```

Then the string is stored as utf-8 in memory.

---

If you use Lazarus/LCL, you can just just display it as usual because the LCL uses utf-8 internally

If you use writeln it works, if the system terminal is utf-8 encoded (e.g. on linux)

Otherwise, you need to convert the string before printing. You can use `UTF8ToAnsi`  of the LCL for this. At least on Linux. Windows is special, because it uses another encoding in the terminal, so you need  `UTF8ToConsole` or `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`, if you want to use `writeln`.

If you want to call Windows api functions, you can use `UTF8ToAnsi` to call the old A-variant, or `UTF8Decode` to call the W-variant.

---

(there is also a `{$codepage utf8}` option to set the string-encoding to utf-8, but it should [not be used](http://wiki.freepascal.org/LCL_Unicode_Support#FPC_codepages) in the current version, because it is very strange and creates a mix of ucs-2 and utf-8)

Comment: I am working in dev-Pascal and when I save file .pas in utf-8, it's still not working. I have a lot of writeln and using converter for each string is too complicated. I use windows. Is there an option to include utf-8 for all files? Pascal is new to me and I'm sorry, I don't understand it all. @BeniBela

Comment: For Windows: If you just want to use writeln, call `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`. You can check, if your strings contain utf-8 with `length('ä') = 2`. Or call `chcp 65001` in the console, *before* calling your program

Comment: How do I use `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` ? Sorry for so many questions, but I can't find the right answer on the internet.

Comment: Just put `windows` in the uses clause and then then `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` somewhere before the first writeln (if `CP_UTF8` is undefined, use `65001` instead)

Comment: I put `{$IFDEF WINDOWS}SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);{$ENDIF}` after begin (main function) and don't work. Change with `65001` and same.

Comment: devpascal has a stoneage version of FPC that probably doesn't grok $codepage

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Which version you recommend?

Comment: 2.6.2 is the latest stable. But you need to be more precise than "don't work". Did you test the length to see if it is stored as utf-8? Does this [example](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=13949.0) work for you? what does it output to the console? If it prints two characters / special character, you are printing utf-8 that is interpreted as ansi. If you get ?, you are printing ansi that is interpreted as utf-8. If you get 5 characters / special character, you are printing utf-8 that is interpreted as ansi that is converted to utf-8 which is again interpreted as ansi...